# aria2c downloading same file from HTTP and FTP in parallel doesn't work

Tags: http, parallel-processing, download, ftp, aria2

The `aria2c` manpage says:

> Download a file from HTTP and FTP servers at the same time
>
> ```
> $ aria2c "http://host1/file.zip" "ftp://host2/file.zip"
> ```

But when I try this, it says "CN:1", that there is only one connection being made (apparently to the first specified URL):

```
10/01 15:06:30 [NOTICE] Downloading 1 item(s)
[#ed323a 120MiB/2.5GiB(4%) CN:1 DL:111KiB ETA:6h26m58s]
```

Why doesn't it say "CN:2"?